# When trying to go back to main page, if condition gives error :(

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project that includes downloading a bunch of data from this website (I have permission).
Anyways, I'm attempting at writing a bot that will do the following:
go into the website
log in
go to packs section of the website (each pack contains x number of clips in different formats)
in each pack download both DNxHQ and H264 formats for each clip
go back to packs page and go into the next pack
repeat until you reach show more button
click it
perform a few methods on the downloaded files
repeat

Most of this can be found in the `process_gallery()` method.
Anyways, when I run it, it goes through the first pack, downloads everything it needs to,
goes back to packs page- and crashes.

This is my code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/PTFQ
And this is my error: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/RYUQ

Keep in mind that this is my first ever python project and I did use a lot of chatGPT.
Please help!

I tried a few things, I tried to do the "try:" thing which just told me that the error stems from this line "if not

```py
pack.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img#showmore")
```

I tried asking chatGPT but couldn't manage to understand what it wanted me to do/what it wanted me to do just didn't work.
I also tried adding the "wait_for_pack_to_load(driver, pack)" so it would wait for the page to load because I thought the error is because it doesnt get enough time to actually reload the page and all the elements within it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).